# What is the alternative method for "- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size" in ios 7

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios7

Can anybody tell me What is the alternative method for `- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size` in ios 7?

This method is deprecated in ios 7. What method should I use that can return the size of string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [With what should I replace the deprecated sizeWithFont:contrainedToSize:lineBreakMode method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18315441/with-what-should-i-replace-the-deprecated-sizewithfontcontrainedtosizelinebrea)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick google search gives this as the first sugestion. never writen anything for ios myself so i dont know if this helps you.

```
 (CGRect)boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize)size options:(NSStringDrawingOptions)options attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes context:(NSStringDrawingContext *)context
```

And here is where i found it: http://www.leapingbytes.com/blog/version_proofing_your_code_arc_twist